# Camera not using Location services when opened via safari

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I designed a website for my company that allows a user to upload a picture(most likely using an iphone or ipad) They go to the form select upload picture and they can choose to take a picture or browse from what has already been taken.

My issue is when camera is opened from safari, location services is not enabled and the picture taken does not contain gps exif headers. However, if the user opens camera takes the picture  then opens safari the picture does contain the gps exif headers.  Is there an option I'm missing or is this a bug/feature of ios?

Also Location services is enabled and both camera and safari websites are listed as while using. And I'm using IOS 9.2.1

Comment: How the safari is trying to capture the photo. I think it is based on the html5. So, check the html code.